# Why can't you vote on a question during review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

During Triage review I can't vote on questions that I'm inspecting.

This in itself is okay to me. But sometimes the review gives feedback and tells me I should vote on questions that are of a high quality.

Of course I can open the link to that question in a new tab - would if the review system wants me to vote on questions, why can't I do that there without a workaround? Just like in the First Post review.